# Magento - Auto set base, small and thumbnail on upload

Tags: image, ce-1.9.0.1, multiple-file-upload

Morning,

We have literally searched all over Stackoverflow and Google to find this solutions but still don't have the right answer.

We're trying to auto-set the Base, Small and Thumbnail options on the first uploaded image, so when uploading multiple images the first image will always have all three options checked.

If anyone has tried and succeeded with find this answer and advice, Thank you.

[image: Catalog Product]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set this type of functionality via code then

```
$_Product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath1, array('media_image', 'thumbnail','small_image','image'), false, false);
```

Pass the argument as `array('media_image', 'thumbnail','small_image','image')` then this image is set as Base, Small and Thumbnail.

If you upload via back-end then you have to set that thing manually.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Keyul Shah, but as you can see we're wanting to do this from within the backend. Do you have any further suggestions and ideas on how we would be able to achieve this ?

Comment: No in back-end you have to do it manually

Comment: No problem, thank you for your time and help keyul